# How can I hide a work item field from some users in TFS 2008?

Tags: tfs, bug-tracking, tfs-workitem

I'm customizing work item templates in TFS 2008 through the PowerTools and I'm wondering is it possible to hide a field (or it's value) for certain users?

For example, let's say I open TFS to my clients so they can submit feature requests. I'd like them to see the work item created, to see the history, changes etc. but I'd like to keep some of the field private and for our internal use.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm, it seems it is not possible YET.

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=254161

"This is a great suggestion. We have added it as a candidate for a future release. It would help us if you could provide a business case for this request. Thanks."

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to create a custom interface to the work items that only exposes the fields you want, while hiding others.  While it would mean some custom development, it would solve the problem.

Comment: How can i integrate such a custom interface with the TFS UI, namely TFS WebAccess? Do you mean COMPLETELY custom UI?

Answer (score -1):

You can make it readonly - that's close? Good luck.
You can use the  rule.